# Seeking out "Robin Hood and Satan's Demons"

Tags: shopping, robin-hood

I'm from Belgium and searching the German version of the Italian movie 'Una Spada per Brando' to buy or to download if no other options are available.

These film, in German, is named 'Robin Hood und die Dämonen des Satans' or 'Robin Hood und die Dämonen des Todes'

I'm searching it because my father saw it once and is eager to see it again. Unfortunately, he nor I can find it. I did find posters and streaming media (although I highly doubt the streaming media is actually what i'm searching for)

The movie is from 1970, more details can be found [here](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0066395/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1).

Answer (score 1):

[This company](http://www.videoscreams.com/2011%20CATALOGUE%20DINO%20FANTASY%20FILMS.htm) appear to have it available for sale (as "Robin Hood and the Demons of Satan").

---

Failing that, [video clips](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lkPdZiM-2K4) relating to the film have been taken down at the request of "[Medusa Film S.p.a and RTI Sp.A.](http://www.medusa.it/)". You might try contacting them directly to see if they have any copies at their disposal.

You may also note that the clip uploaded onto youtube was put there by a company called "AtlasVisuals". A quick google search indicates that the company itself is defunct but was [owned and operated](http://web.archive.org/web/20060202054020/http://atlasvisuals.com/) by a man named Brian (Simmons?) living in the Dallas area. His email was atlasvisuals@cableone.net